# Fetching values as ordered map from database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, collections

I am working on business requirement where I need to fetch two field values as key/value pairs in  an order. I am using mysql and hibernate for doing db operatuons.

My table contains three colomns (fieldId,FieldName,FieldType) with fieldId as primary key. My requirement is to fetch fieldIds and FieldNames values as ordered map based on fieldType.

here is my sample table data.

```
FieldId  FieldName  Type
1        f1         x
2        f2         x
3        f3         x
4        f4         y
```

I want to have all fieldIds and fieldNames as key value pairs in ascendingr(based on fieldId) for specific field type say "x". Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is you have a Hibernate entity that correlates to your field configuration you provided:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class FieldEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "FieldId")
  private Long fieldId;
  @Column(name = "FieldName")
  private String fieldName;
  @Column(name = "Type")
  private String type;
}
```

The first step would be to fetch the actual data rows themselves based on your requirement, which is by type.  You can elect to have the database perform the sort for you or do it yourself in java code.  This depends on reuse of your query.  I'll show you both.

**Sort With Query**

First, add the following annotation to your `FieldEntity` class just below `@Table`.

```
@NamedQuery(
  name = "FieldEntity.findByType", 
  query = "FROM FieldEntity e WHERE e.type = :type ORDER BY e.fieldId")
```

Named queries are a great feature as they are parsed by the ORM provider typically at startup, informing you of any query errors and also reduce runtime costs since they're pre-parsed.

The next step is to use this NamedQuery in order to get the results from hibernate.

```
// construct a hibernate query using named query, specifying the type parameter.
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("FieldEntity.findByType").setString("type", type);

// Now iterate and capture results
List<FieldEntity> results = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object[] row : query.list()) {
  FieldEntity e = row.get(0);
  results.add(e);
}
```

Once you have the results of your query (already sorted by `FieldId`), it's a simple iteration loop and adding them to a map based on your business requirements.  This type of logic is typically something I'd either see in a business use case class.

```
public Map<Long, String> getFieldEntityMapByType(String type) {
  List<FieldEntity> results = // call DAO and get list.
  Map<Long, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  for(FieldEntity entity : results) 
    map.put(entity.getFieldId(), entity.getFieldName());
  return map;
}
```

Since the results are already sorted, I use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order as I iterate the result set.

**Sort Without Query**

In this case, your `@NamedQuery` would not include an *ORDER BY* clause and instead, I would use a `SortedMap` rather than `LinkedHashMap` and the code remains the same.

The `SortedMap` makes sure the entries are sorted based on the natural sort order of your field ids as they're added to the map.

**Conclusion**

The benefit to the latter approach is you can alter the sort behavior by use case without impacting the database access code, but the cost impact is that the sorting is being done in the application server's memory.  Depending on the number of entities in question, this could become problematic with large result sets.

The former approach works well on larger result sets and can be optimized by using a criteria based query rather than named query for altering sort order at runtime simply at the cost of a query parse each execution.